# Visual Studio Code area name

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can any one tell me the name of this area in VS Code.

[Can anyone tell me the name of this area?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjS7i.png)

Answer (score 0):

That part is called editor toolbar.

Check out more about the [User Interface](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface)

Comment: Thank you for your responces so can you please help me out ? I have one problem with that I have downloaded the preview extension so at first I got the symbol over there for preview but when I install another preview extension so after that preview icon get disappear from there

Comment: What happens when you disable that extension and restart vs code?

Comment: Not a single change seen when I restart or disable I have also tried by restarting my computer but no changes

Comment: Which icon do you mean by preview icon?